# Google Maps APIv2: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.settings

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I have been struggling to include a Google Map in my android project. I have been through a variety of questions right here on stackoverflow, and still can't get a map to display.

I am running Eclipse SDK 4.2.2 on a 64-bit Windows 7 box. I have retrieved my SHA1 and gotten my APIv2 key from Google.

I have also tried installing the .apk file on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, and I get the same result as I do when using the emulator.

**Screenshot of my Android emulator:**
I can't post an image, so here's a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9qam1w2762z9he/emulator_screen_cap.png

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.maptest2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission
    android:name="com.test.maptest2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.test.maptest2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.maptest2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="myAPIKey" />
</application>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.test.maptest2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing internet permission  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: mention permissions and above rahu said also regenerate the new api keys and uninstall app from device and clean the project...try now ...